# Convert string date value to date format value

Tags: php

I have a date in string given format :

```
$bookingDate1 : 20180928
```

We have to convert the date format like :

```
$bookingDate : 28-09-2018
```

I have tried :

```
$bookingDate = substr($bookingDate1,6,2)."-".substr($bookingDate1,4,2)."-".substr($bookingDate1,0,4);
```

It gives correct result but i need better solution.

Thanks

Comment: _“It gives correct result but i need better solution.”_ - this makes rather little sense as a question, because it lacks any criteria by which you would consider one solution “better” than another. Please specify what exactly you are looking for in such cases, or at least what actual problem you have with what you already got.

Comment: You can use regex that is simpler

Answer (score 0):

You can use php [date()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) function.

**Example**

```
$date = "20180928"; 
echo date("d-m-Y",strtotime($date));
```

**Output**

```
28-09-2018
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use "DateTime::createFromFormat"

```
$date = date_create_from_format('d/m/Y:H:i:s', $bookingDate);
```

If you want the timestamp then follow it up with

```
$date->getTimestamp();
```

you can check it out here https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_date_create_from_format.asp

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$bookingDate1 = 20180928;
echo Date('d-m-Y',strtotime($bookingDate1));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `createFromFormat` to make dare object from your current format

```
    <?php

        $str = "20180928";
        $date = DateTime::createFromFormat('Ymd', $str);
        echo $date->format('Y-m-d');

     ?>
```

[Live Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/d426cdd71ebe63ee49879d67816bbba9de70b579)

Answer (score 0):

Use strtotime() on thew string date and then apply date('Y-m-d') function to convert it back to the date format.

```
$bookingDate1 = strtotime('20180928');
```

> The Above Syntax will convert the string to the UNIX TIME FORMAT. After that we have to apply the `date()` function to convert it back.

```
$bookingDate = date('d-m-Y',$bookingDate1);
```

> This will convert the string formatted date to the `Year-month-date format`. Now the Output of the Date will be as follows.

```
echo $bookingDate; // 28-09-2018
```

For Different Date Formats Kindly refer Here: http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.date.php